# How can I change the name of the jar file after siging it - Apache ANT

Tags: java, ant, jar

I am signing my jars using following ant commands.

```
<signjar alias="${alias}" keypass="${keypass}" 
            storepass="${storepass}" 
            keystore="${keystorefile}" 
            signedjar="${dist.dir}/${jar.signed.fileName}" 
            lazy="true">
            <fileset dir="${dist.dir}">
                <include name="*.jar" />
                <include name="lib/*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </signjar>
```

For single file it is fine that I can change the name of the jars file after signing it,
but when I have multiple jars the above line is not useful, what i am trying to accomplish is ,

for example

If the unsigned jar file name is `ab.jar after signing it I want to prepend`Signed_`to it's name like`Signed_ab.jar` and so on for all the jars i have in my fileset.

Can anyone tell me how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ant jar command/task like below in your build script :

```
<jar basedir="bin" destfile="Signed_${jar-name}.jar">
```

btw, you missed to type the command you're using, in your question.

Comment: but where to get jar-name that is being signed this is the question.

Answer (score 0):

The signjar task can take a `mapper` defining how to translate the input file name into an output file name:

```
<signjar alias="${alias}" keypass="${keypass}" 
            storepass="${storepass}" 
            keystore="${keystorefile}" 
            destdir="${dist.dir}"
            lazy="true">
    <fileset dir="${dist.dir}">
        <include name="*.jar" />
        <include name="lib/*.jar" />
        <!-- since we're dumping signed JARs in the same dir as the source
             ones, we need to prevent already-signed JARs from being signed
             again.  A better approach might be to put the Signed_* JARs in
             a different directory -->
        <exclude name="**/Signed_*" />
    </fileset>
    <regexpmapper handledirsep="yes"
                  from="^(.*?)/([^/]*)$$" to="\1/Signed_\2" />
</signjar>
```

Comment: hi i tried your solution bu it gives me an following error BUILD FAILED
F:\workspace\Pack200AntTask\signbuild.xml:31: Cannot map source file to anything sensible: F:\workspace\Pack200AntTask\unsignedjars\lwjgl_applet_util.jar

Total time: 187 milliseconds

Comment: @Mihir I thought `handledirsep` was supposed to deal with the difference between forward and backward slashes... I think a much easier solution would be to keep the file names the same but put the signed files in a different directory, i.e. just set `destdir="signedjars"` and remove the `regexpmapper`.

Comment: Yes i can do it.but ant can not accomplish my above goal ?

Comment: and can you help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20525356/adding-attribute-to-jars-manifest-via-ant-task as well ?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can write couple of macros & call 'signJarsParallel' macro once for every directory for which you want to sign jars.

This is not tested code. You can give it a try. It makes use running tasks parallely & hence increasing speed & signs to temporary-prefixed name you want :

```
<macrodef name="signMyJars">
<element name="myJar" implicit="true"/>
<sequential>
    <signjar alias="${alias}" keypass="${keypass}"
             storepass="${storepass}"
             keystore="${keystorefile}"
             lazy="true">
        <myJar/>
    </signjar>
</sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Call only below macro inside your ant target.

```
<macrodef name="signJarsParallel">
<attribute name="dirName"/>
<sequential>
    <for param="file" parallel="true" threadCount="5">
        <path>
            <fileset dir="@{dirName}">
                <include name="*.jar"/>
                <include name="lib/*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </path>
        <signMyJars>
            <fileset file="Signed_@{file}.jar"/>
        </signMyJars>
    </for>

</sequential>
</macrodef>
```