# Adding Attribute to JAR's Manifest Via ANT TASK

Tags: java, ant, jar

all i am stuck with an issue. I have 14 third party jars.I am signing those jars with comodo code sign certificate successfully via ant task.

**Now i want to accomplish that whenever i sign those jars i need to add some attributes to jar's manifest file ,**

How can i do that ?

I found some manifest task inside jar task but did not find anything while signing.

all those jars are third party jars and already packed so i think do not need to compile and pack them from the source.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd probably have to do something like this for each jar file:

```
<unzip src="${jar.file.location}" dest="${manifest.dest.dir}">
    <patternset>
        <include name="**/MANIFEST.MF"/>
    </patternset>
</unzip>

<manifest file="${manifest.dest.dir}/MANIFEST.MF" mode="update">
    <attribute name="${myAttribute}" value="${myAttributeValue}"/>
</manifest>

<jar update="true" destfile="${jar.file.location}" basedir="${manifest.dest.dir}"/>
```

Comment: hi thanks bill for quick answer , but is there a way to automate it for all jars like any loop kind logic ?

Comment: I'm a little rusty on ant, but I don't think so. However, you could put the solution I suggested inside a target Foo, then have a separate target Bar that calls Boo for each jar file using AntCall, in which you set some property (jar.file.location) to the file location with the call. Yes, it's a pain in the patoot, but that's the way I've solved this kind of problem in the past.

Comment: I haven't used it yet, but I hear Ivy is a great tool for dependency management, and it might solve this problem for you as well. http://ant.apache.org/ivy/